# jqgrid userData posting null on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid and a form. When the grid is refreshed, I am attempting to send the values of the form to the server side handler. For testing, I'm using just one variable in the form. Firebug shows that jqgrid is passing the field name, but the value is always  null regardless of what is selected.

According the the jqgrid docs, I should be handling this using the postData variable:

postData: {POINIT : jQuery('#POINIT').val()}

I've also tested this  to ensure that calling the jQuery to get the value works on other parts of the page -- just not when the grid is refreshed.

Here's the relevant code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(funcion(){ 
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'poquery.php',  
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames:['PO Number ','Date','Vendor','Dept','Buyer','Terms'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'PONUMB', index:'PONUMB', width:65}, 
      {name:'PODATE', index:'PODATE', width:70},
      {name:'POVEND', index:'POVEND', width:70},
      {name:'POIDPT', index:'POIDPT', width:70},
      {name:'POINIT', index:'POINIT', width:70},
      {name:'TERMS', index:'TERMS', width:70},
    ],
postData: {POINIT : jQuery('#POINIT').val()},
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'PONUMB',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Purchase orders'
   }).navGrid('#gridpager',{view:false,edit:false,add:false, del:false}, 
{}, // use default settings for edit
{}, // use default settings for add
{},  // delete instead that del:false we need this
{multipleSearch : true}, // enable the advanced searching
{closeOnEscape:true} 
);

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This works for me, so I suspect you either aren't setting what you think you are in the grid initialization or you're overwriting it. I've never seen postData fail, and I set it much like you do above. Debug the val() result!

Answer (score 7):

I'm way late with this reply, but the trick is to use a function:

postData: {POINIT : function() { return $('#POINIT').val(); }}